# Excel Comparison Formula

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to reconcile one list to another using the formula:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,Sheet3!B:B)),"NO","YES")
```

Worked, however I noticed that I had a false negative.  In the example provided, without showing the actual information, you will see how the first item shows NO but the other two state YES.  Same source of information.  When I did a simple if formula to see if it that cell matches without using an array, it shows it matches.  What am I missing, I validated that information is both formatted to General and it worked for the other two items.

[image]

Comment: Everything looks OK so it can only be a typo or something silly, maybe a space at the end of the "Item 1" on the left or maybe it's not referencing the correct cell.  You've included the formula on the sheet but you're not showing the formula that is currently in the "NO" cell.

Comment: The formula that is in the No cell is =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,Sheet3!B:B,0))"NO","YES").  I thought it could be information not matching but the formula to the right works.  So it's saying that those two are the same.  I thought I could have the YES and NO backward but then Item 1 and Item two are wrong.  Does ISERROR have a size limitation possibly?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be in.  256 is the lucky #.  I thought that was an issue with VLOOKUP but didn't know it was with IF(ISERROR).  So any ideas on how to do a full comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B3=Sheet3!$B$1:$B$1000))>0,"Yes","No")
```

The reference on Sheet3 needs to be limited to only the dataset and not be a full column reference.